# jQuery not working for select only one checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have built a table with four rows and eight columns, each with a checkbox. I want only one checkbox to be allowed to check per row. I am trying to use jquery to do this. Logically, it works in jsfiddle but it does not work locally for me. I did use an alert first to make sure jQuery is being loaded first.

Here is my code below. The problem is, I can still check multiple checkboxes per row when I should only be allowed to check one:

```
 <body>
    <h2>Checkbox Test</h2>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/mytesting/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function onLoadAlert() {
        alert('Sup');
    }

    $(document).ready(onLoadAlert);
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {

          // uncheck sibling checkboxes (checkboxes on the same row)
          $(this).siblings().prop('checked', false);

          // uncheck checkboxes in the same column
          $('div').find('input[type="checkbox"]:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').not(this).prop('checked', false);

        });
    </script>

    <table border="1">

    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th><b>COST</b></th>
        <th colspan="3">Reduced Cost</th>
        <th>Neutral</th>
        <th colspan="3">Increased Cost</th>
        <th>Don't Know</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>High</th>
        <th>Medium</th>
        <th>Low</th>
        <th>No effect</th>
        <th>Low</th>
        <th>Medium</th>
        <th>High</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Capital cost</td>
        <div>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix1" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix2" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix3" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix4" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix5" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix6" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix7" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix8" value="1"></td>
        </div>

    </tr>



    </tbody>
```

Comment: Why not use radio input?  This is exactly what they are designed for

Comment: Your javascript must be placed after the elements you are trying to select. Or wrapped in a document.ready block like you are doing with the alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `input` elements are not siblings, because they have different parents – the `td` elements:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix1" value="1"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="matrix2" value="1"></td>
```

That's why this doesn't work:

```
$(this).siblings().prop('checked', false);
```

Instead, do this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('input').not(this).prop('checked', false);
```

[**Fiddle 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/npc1opbu/)

---

Alternatively, you could use radio buttons having the same `name`:

```
 <td><input type="radio" name="matrix"></td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="matrix"></td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="matrix"></td>
```

That way, you wouldn't need any JavaScript.

[**Fiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/rmfe95qw/)

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be a lot simpler to just do this

```
var checkBoxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');
$('table').on('click', 'input[type=checkbox]', function () {
  checkBoxes.prop('checked', false);
  $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

And you have a **div** inside a **tr**.